# Scanning a File to compare string. Average of comparisons

Tags: math, compare, average, code-complexity

I have two text file, that are two set of strings. `First_file.txt` (X strings) and `Second_file.txt` (N strings)

```
First_file.txt

string1
string2
string3
...
stringX


Second_file.txt

string1
string2
string3
...
stringN
```

I have compared these two files in this way: i took the `string1` from `First_file` and i've scanned the `Second_file`, line by line. If i find the same string, break and restart with `string2` from `First_file`.

So the best case is that there is a match on the first line, the worst case is no match, so i have to scan the entire file.

I'm interested in the average numbers of comparisons: is right `N/2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average number of comparisons depends on the length of both file 1 and 2. Each line in file 1 is compared in average with N/2 strings in file 2. Then the total average number of comparisons will be X * N/2 (being X the number of lines in file 1 and N the number of lines in file 2).